# Bound on Coefficients

Tags: quadratics

For real $a,b,c$ the following holds $|ax^2+bx+c|\le 1 ; \forall x\in [0,1]$.Show that $|a|+|b|+|c|\le 17$.
Cant show that the equality holds.I always get the lesser bounds.

Comment: can u share ur  approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $P$ is your polynomial, you have $c=P(0)$, $\frac{a}{4}+\frac{b}{2}+c=P(1/2)$, $a+b+c=P(1)$. Compute $a,b,c$ in function of $P(0),P(1/2),P(1)$.

Comment: the bound comes out to be 19.

Comment: I have found $a=2P(1)-4P(1/2)+2P(0)$, $b=-P(1)+4P(1/2)-3P(0)$, $c=P(0)$, but perhaps I am wrong. What do you find for $a,b,c$ ?

Comment: you are right.:)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum of $|ax^2+bx+c|\le 1$ in $[0,1]$ can be $x=0,1$ (border points of the interval $[0,1]$) or the critical point of $ax^2+bx+c$, namely $x=-b/2a$...